# getDataFileName returns a non-existent directory

Tags: haskell, file-io, cabal, leksah

I can't get data files to be packaged up in a cabal dist. The directory that is produced with `getDataFileName` doesn't exist after installing the package.

Main.hs:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import Paths_mypackage

main = do file <- getDataFileName "mydata.txt"
          putStrLn file
          print =<< readFile file
```

mypackage.cabal (generated by Leksah after browsing for the file):

```
 data-files: /Users/peter/Documents/haskell/mypackage/data/mydata.txt
 mydata-dir: ""
```

Output:

```
mypackage: /Users/peter/.cabal/share/mypackage-0.0.1/mydata.txt: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
/Users/peter/.cabal/share/mypackage-0.0.1/mydata.txt
```

Comment: In a .cabal file, don't use absolute paths. All data files should be under the package directory and referred to by relative paths.

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned, the cabal file is generated by Leksah. I'll add that to the post (and I will try to edit it manually to see if it works that way).

Comment: No that didn't help. The directory `~/.cabal/share/mypackage-0.0.1/` still doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok got it! I had to use a path, relative to the cabal file AND use that full relative path to access it (which should have been obvious).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines in the .cabal file should be

```
data-files: mydata.txt
data-dir:   data
```

Then cabal will install the data file in the appropriate location, `/Users/peter/.cabal/share/mypackage-0.0.1/mydata.txt` in your case, and the programme will work.

Comment: It's worth noting that I don't like to distribute empty data files as place-holders, so what I do instead is use `getDataDir` and [`createDirectoryIfMissing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v:createDirectoryIfMissing)
(.